# A graph with a disjoint matching contains components that are either paths or even circuits.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I wish to prove the following result:

> Let $M$ and $M'$ be disjoint matchings in a graph $G = (V,E)$. Show that every component
>   of the graph $(V, M \cup M')$ is a path or an even circuit.

We just started learning about matchings, which is a set of edges that pairwise have no endpoint in common. Formally it means that if $M$ is a matching, we know that $M \subseteq E$ and for $e, e' \in M$ it holds that $e \cap e'= \emptyset$.

Now I need to make some sort of disctinction for union of two of these matchings $M$ and $M'$, such that $M \cap M '= \emptyset$. I do not see what kind of distinction to make, I also feel a little bit overwhelmed by the "every component" part. It feels very general. Can somebody offer a useful hint, how to proceed/start a good distinction? Basically what I think I need to do is show that if $C$ is a circuit, it has to be even.

---

scrap paper:

Suppose we colour matching $M$ blue and we colour matching $M'$ red. Then the idea is that for an even circuit, these two colours alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges in $M$ do not intersect and edges in $M'$ do not intersect either. The only way edges in $(V(G),M\cup M')$ can intersect is between edges in $M$ and edges in $M'$. We can't have three edges intersect at the same vertex. That is because two of those edges both belong to either $M$ or $M'$,  But they can't intersect by definition of a matching. Hence the degree of each vertex in $(V(G),M\cup M')$ is at most two. Hence vertices in each components is at most 2. So then that means the component is either a path or a cycle.

Comment: $M$ and $M'$ are set of edges, $M \cap M'= \emptyset$ means no edges in common between the two set of edges, but they could still share a same vertex.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I'm going to continue thinking for a while how to formalise that such a cycle/circuit needs to be an even circuit. I mean if it were of odd length, it would end at the same colour as it would start. Consider a triangle as an example, we start red, blue, red. This is not a matching.

Comment: Oh , that's precisely the argument. If it is of odd length we run into a problem because it violates it being a matching. It really HAS to alternate between the two. It's actually the same argument as for a vertex of degree 3. We cannot have two edges belonging to the same matching meet at the same vertex!

Comment: you cannot bicolor an odd cycle

Comment: Yes that's a result we discussed in class. Thank you. - this was fun :D